# Cannot change UDP fragmentation offload

Tags: networking, rhel, drivers, network-interface

I have a Dell PowerEdge R740 server with an Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller x710 for 10GbE SFP+ network interface. I have installed RHEL 8 on it. I am trying to enable UDP fragmentation offload like this:

```
$ sudo ethtool --offload eno1 ufo on
```

I get this message:

```
Cannot change UDP fragmentation offload  
Cannot change any device features.
```

eno1 has SFP+ DAC cable. Is the issue because of SFP+ cable? or any driver that I might be missing?

Comment: What device is it exactly?

Comment: It's a Dell PowerEdge r740 server.

Comment: I mean the network device.

Comment: Are you asking about NIC, cable or switch?

Comment: Asking about the NIC.

Comment: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller x710 for 10GbE SFP+

Answer (score 0):

From the output you provided, probably UFO is not supported by the driver and has nothing to do with the cable.

Comment: I checked it with ethtool --show-offload eno1. UFO is off. It is not off[fixed]. If ethtool shows UFO as off [fixed], that means it's not supported in the driver.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the kernel.org Git commit that added the UFO feature.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e89e9cf539a28df7d0eb1d0a545368e9920b34ac)

Note the following:

> This patches **uses scatter-gather feature** of skb to generate large UDP
> datagram.
>
> [...]
>
> The skb->ip_summed will be set to CHECKSUM_HW
> indicating that **hardware has to do checksum calculation**. Hardware should
> compute the UDP checksum of complete datagram and also ip header checksum of
> each fragmented IP packet.

So if you have scatter-gather and/or TX hardware checksumming disabled, it might not be possible to enable the UDP fragmentation offload feature, although the feature is available in the NIC+driver. You would need to enable the other required features first.

That would be:

```
sudo ethtool --offload eno1 sg on tx on ufo on
```